# tee and grep at the same time (shell)?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm trying to run a server that writes to $log (a txt file) and then find all the text in the logfile that starts with [1] and put it in another file. Here's my attempt. `tee -a $log` works along with everything else. The grep command doesn't though.

```
run="tail -n0 -f -s 0.01 $cmds | (while true; do $tron --userconfigdir $userconfigdir --userdatadir $userdatadir --vardir $var; done) | tee -a $log | grep '^\[1\]' > ${var}logs/chatlogs.log"
```

What can be done to copy all the text from `tee -a $log` starting with [1] to another file?

Comment: What's the problem with grep ? do you get an error ? No output in `${var}logs/chatlogs.log` ? No output in `${var}logs/chatlogs.log` even though *you've thoroughly verified there should be somewhere there* (by running the grep on `$log` independently, for example) ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. There is no output to chatlogs.log

Comment: I don't believe that the problem is with the grep, but before it. If you remove the `tee -a $log` does it work? probably not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normally fine to do this:

```
tail -f /var/log/mylog | egrep '^<txttomatch>' | tee /tmp/watchlog
```

Naturally, you only need tee if you wish to have console output as well as copying to file.
If you are starting and stopping this process you may want to pass the `-a` switch to tee.

Comment: would txttomatch be in `<>` or without

Comment: I used <txttomatch> to be a placeholder. So if you wanted lines starting jonny or Jonny you could egrep -i "^jonny". The ^ anchors the pattern to the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

What did you get when running it?

Try the alternative:

```
... tee -a $log >(grep '^\[1\]' > ${var}logs/chatlogs.log)
```

Comment: no luck, still a blank file

Comment: Are you sure the output including some lines beginning with `[1]`: `grep '^\[1\]' $log`?

Comment: Yes for example, this is the file $log is being tee'd too: http://pastebin.com/NaubAKqu

Comment: Don't know why it didn't work with you. Try again with: `tee >(grep '^\[1\]' > ${var}logs/chatlogs.log) >> $log`

Comment: that didn't work either :(